# Vagrant - Apache - Centos7-Lamp - Synced folders not working for Web

Tags: apache, vagrant

I am fairly new at Vagrant. (I have several versions of Homestead working. But now I want an environment without Laravel, etc.)

So, I have vagrant installed on Windows 10. I have downloaded Gigasavvy/centos7-LAMP box. It is installed and I can access the default index.php from Chrome.

Now I want to put my web files in the public_html file on the guest os.

I simply want to have my host os folder synced with the /public_html file on the guest system so my web pages will work. When I ssh into the guest the and do a pwd in the desired destination I get what is shown below:

```
[ vagrant@localhost.localdomain (Tue Apr 11): ~/public_html ]$ pwd
/home/vagrant/public_html
```

However apparently the folder is synced with  /vagrant and all the files I put on the host system show up in the /vagrant folder off the system root as shown below -

```
[ vagrant@localhost.localdomain (Tue Apr 11): /vagrant ]$ pwd
/vagrant
```

I thought I understood the vagrantfile, however with homestead it uses a .yaml file. I am using the default vagrant file with the only changes are the

```
config.vm.box = "Gigasavvy/centos7-LAMP"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 4568
config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/david/vagrant/centosAp/public_html", "/public_html"
```

In the vagrantfile I have tried so many variants of the synced folder line modifying the destination

- "/home/vagrant/public_html"
- "/vagrant/public_html"
- "/public_html"

and many others but it continues to write to the folder above.
I am modifying the vagrantfile in the project folder.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As per the log request
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.14
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/David/vagrant/centosAp
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

Comment: can you show the log file when running `vagrant up` at the end when it says  `default: Mounting shared folders...` there should be a line something like `/public_html => C:/Users/david/vagrant/centosAp/public_html`

Comment: default: Guest Additions Version: 5.0.14
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.1
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/David/vagrant/centosAp
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

Comment: so you dont have a shared folder on `/public_html` only the default `/vagrant` is synced - are you sure you run `vagrant up` with your modified Vagrantfile ?

Comment: Other than starting vagrant in the "project folder" where the vagrant file is located, I don't know another way to confirm its the one being used.